# Implementing parallelism in a recursive function in HTML

Tags: java, html, parallel-processing

So I'm trying to create a button in Java using the Swing library.  When you click the button, it's supposed to find the shortest route in a map.  Does anybody know how to add in an action listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. I do not think this is the best way to go about making a button connected to a map. Check out http://s.goel.im/wDM

Comment: Oh I think that's better than what I had going on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,

> Does anybody know how to add in an action listener?

Then yes. [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) has [`addActionListener(ActionListener l)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29). So you create a class that implements [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) and then pass an instance of that class to your button. Something like this,

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Hello");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Hello clicked"); // <-- or, find the shortest route in a map
  }
});
```

Comment: What about the other part of my question?

Comment: @user3861617 What's the other part of your question?